# Can non Variant parameter become vbError?

Tags: vba, error-handling

I'm going through some vba code and found the equivalent of the following fragment. Can the condition in the `If` ever be true, if yes, how?

```
Public Sub check(param As String)
    If VarType(param) = vbError Then
    ...
```

What if `param` was defined as `Variant` how can the `param` become an error?

```
Public Sub check2(param As Variant)
    If VarType(param) = vbError Then
    ...
```

Based on the comments, the statement could be simplified to:

```
If IsError(param) Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, only `Variant` can become `vbError`. You can create errors with the [CVErr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/cverr-function) function.

```
Sub errorType()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim s As String

    On Error GoTo finish
    v = CVErr(13)

    Debug.Print VarType(v) = vbError 'True: Variant can become error

    s = CVErr(13) 'Jumps to finish
    Debug.Print "String can become error"
    Exit Sub
finish:
    Debug.Print "String can't become error"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

A string is VarType 8 and is fixed to it, so the condition in your first example can never be true.
The second, however, can occur. If you read the value of an cell holding an invalid value (eg `#VALUE`) into a variant, it will get the VarType 10 (vbError)

Just as an example:

```
Sub testVBError()
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 1) = 3
    .Cells(1, 2) = 0
    .Cells(1, 3).Formula = "=A1/B1" ' Divide by zero
    Dim v As Variant
    v = .Cells(1, 3).Value
    Debug.Print VarType(v)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So instead of making something as simple as `IsError(param)` the OP's colleague has used `VarType(param)=vbError`... I am impressed! :)

Answer (score 1):

`vbError` is an enum. It is equal to 10. If VarType(param) is 10, then it would be true.

Here is how to play a bit and to make it work with Variant:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Variant
    i = "a"
    Debug.Print VarType(i + 2)

    If VarType(i + 10) = vbError Then
        Debug.Print "VarType equals vbError"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't answer `how can the param become an error`

Comment: Note that the type of `param` in the first example is `String`